# Repeatedly call a function: Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Basically, I want to create a function that takes a list of integers and another list (this list can be of any type) and produce another list that has the elements in it from the "other list" at intervals specified by the list of integers.  If I input:

> ixs [2,3,1] [3,2,1]
>   
>  [2,1,3]

So far I have:

```
ix :: Int -> [a] -> a
ix a [] = error "Empty list"
ix 1 (x:xs) = x
ix a (x:xs) = ix (a-1) xs

ixs :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
ixs [] _ = [] 
ixs _ [] = []
ixs (x:xs) (y) = ix x y: []
```

With this code I only get one value returned like so:

> ixs [1,2] [2,1]
>   
>  [2]

How can I call the `ix` function repeatedly on `(x:xs)` so that it returns all the values I want?

Edit: I want to do this without using any standard prelude functions.  I just want to use recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse the order of the arguments

```
ix' :: [a] -> Int -> a
ix' [] a = error "Empty list"
ix' (x:xs) 1 = x
ix' (x:xs) a = ix' xs (a-1)
```

to make it easier to map `ix` over a list of indeces:

```
ixs' :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
ixs' xs is = map (ix' xs) is
```

Like this:

```
> ixs' "Hello Mum" [1,5,6,1,5,6,1,5]
"Ho Ho Ho"
```

but it would be nicer to use `flip` to swap the arguments - `ix'` is just `flip ix`, so you could do

```
ixs :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
ixs is xs = map (flip ix xs) is
```

which you then call the way round you'd planned:

```
> ixs [1,5,6,1,5,6,1,5] "Hello Mum"
"Ho Ho Ho"
```

Comment: Thank you!  This really helped me.  I never thought about using map and flip in this function.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This is (almost) a map of an indexing ("getting the value at") of the first list over the second list

```
import Data.List ((!!))
-- (!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a

ixs :: [Int] -> [b] -> [b]
ixs ary ixes = map (ary !!) ixes
```

But you also have wraparound when you index a 3-element list by `(3 mod 3 = 0)`, so we ought to just map `mod` over the indexes

```
ixs ary ixes = map (ary !!) (map (`mod` length ary) ixes)
```

And then we can simplify to "pointless style"

```
ixs ary = map (ary !!) . map (`mod` length ary)
```

which reads nicely as "map the indices modulo the array length then map the array indexing over the resultant indices". And it gives the right result

```
> ixs [2,3,1] [3,2,1] 
[2,1,3]
```

---

To break down the Prelude function and `Data.List` function, we have

```
(!!) :: [b] -> Int -> b
(x:_)  !! 0  = x
(_:xs) !! n
 | n > 0     = xs !! (n-1)
 | otherwise = error "List.(!!): negative argument."
_      !! _  = error "List.(!!): index too large."
```

and

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
ixs :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
ixs idx a = map (`ix` a) idx
```

What you want to do is map your index function across all the values in the list of
indices to index the second list. Note that your `ix` function is just `!!` function, but starts indexing from 1 instead of 0.